# How fetch post meta and its taxonomy and terms value by post id

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a web portal where I have to filter some data using post id.

**Here is the situation:**
 I have some course (custom post) such as food technology, B.tech which are linked with college (post meta of course post) and college has some states (taxonomy linked with college).

SO:  Food Technology has => ABC, XYZ college with taxonomy values => A1, B1 States

I successfully get college linked with states but not according to a specific course eg. food technology course as filter fetches all colleges linked with all course not with a specific one.

**here is the code**

```
    $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'college',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'State',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'delhi',

            )
        ),
    );
   $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   if($loop->have_posts()) {
   while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); 
    echo get_the_title();  // college title linked with terms delhi
   endwhile;
   }
```

**Help need:** 
where should I pass post id, of course, to get only linked course college with term Delhi only?

Comment: did you saved it as a post meta i mean can you get it by this function example ? 
`print_r(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'course_id',true));`

Comment: if you have set correctly the post meta. it should showing id of the course